# Open CV (Python) - Abnormal shape blob detection for brain tumors

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mesh

I'm trying to identify brain tumors with blob detection in Open CV, but so far, Open CV only detects tiny circles in brain MRIs, but never the tumor itself.

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import SimpleBlobDetector_create, SimpleBlobDetector_Params
import numpy as np

# Read image
def blobber(filename):
    im = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Set up the detector with default parameters.
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()

    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

    # Filter by Area.
    params.filterByArea = True
    params.minArea = 50

    # Filter by Circularity
    params.filterByCircularity = True
    params.minCircularity = 0

    # Filter by Convexity
    params.filterByConvexity = True
    params.minConvexity = 0.1

    # Create a detector with the parameters
    ver = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
    if int(ver[0]) < 3 :
        detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
    else : 
        detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

    # Detect blobs.
    keypoints = detector.detect(im)

    # Draw detected blobs as red circles.
    # cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
    im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im,keypoints,np.array([]),(0,0,255),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

    # Show keypoints
    cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here's what happens when I feed the program an image of a b/w contrasted brain (I contrasted the brain so the tumor would appear in black, and the rest of the brain would be mostly white):

The tumor is not a perfect circle, by any means, but it's clearly the biggest "blob" in the brain. Open CV can't pick it up, I suspect because it has a black outer shell, and a white core.

[image]

Only when I choose a more distinguishable tumor, without a large white inner core, can it pick up the tumor.
[image]

Any advice? I need to be able to peel these blobs (once they work accurately) out of the original pictures and use their keypoints to reconstruct the entire 3D tumor in the brain from JUST the 2D tumor in each slice. I'm a bit far removed from that step, but this blob detector issue is the crucial link between 2D and 3D. Appreciate all help!

Comment: I am not a doctor, but could you upload another picture stating the position of the tumor?

Comment: You mean like the oncologist's annotation of where the tumor is? If that's what you mean, I can't find it for this set of MR scans.

Comment: You could try a different approach rather than using a binary image...

Comment: What would that approach be?

Comment: uploading the original image would help

Comment: Here's a link to what the original image looks like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJXjT3AXXHlcTNUVU5mYl9sYVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DeanD can you provide the source for dataset?

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to pass filename, it might be b/w images of brain so i think each image will have different blobs at differetn place, so you may need to change params.minArea =50 value to different different value for each image. so i suggest you to use other ML model and not only OpenCV to detect blob.

Comment: this isn't an answer but a comment... please provide specific details and codes as needed to get it qualified as an answer...

Answer (score -1):

probaply the largest blob is the skull itself.
if you distract the largest blob, and keep the next big thing use the contour as outsides